# Validation rule to prevent change if Status has specific value but let change status

Tags: apex, validation-rule, validation, administration, developer

[image]I have a situation where I want to prevent some Profiles from changing any value of field after certain status but I can change the status no other fields values. i.e.

I have status as picklist values: Draft, Processed and so on..

So I want that I can do changes in fields in Draft Status once the Status is changed to Processed or Other status I cannot change any field values except status.

I wrote a validation rule for it but it is wrong for me no runtime error.., its not letting me change status from draft, more over it is letting me change field value too but I want that I can change Status but not the field values after status is changed to Processed after Draft Status. Can someone help me writing. The Validation I am writing is :

```
ISCHANGED(Status__c) && ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status__c), "Draft") && ($Profile.Name = 'Distributor');
```

#Salesforce

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please elaborate on what you mean by "it is failing." Are you getting syntax error when saving your Validation Rule? Are you getting a run-time error? Are you seeing behavior that is not what your are wanting/expecting?

Comment: @Moonpie the validation I wrote is not working for me I want Something else thats what I meant from failing.

Comment: "Not working" is not much different from "it is failing." Details are what are needed so someone can better try to help you. Exactly what do you mean by "not working?" Are you getting a syntax error when saving your Validation Rule? Are you getting a run-time error? Are you seeing behavior that is not what your are wanting/expecting (if so, please edit your question to add *exactly* what behavior you are seeing)?

Comment: @Moonpie Now is it fine??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to write a validation rule for each field:

```
AND(NOT(ISPICKVAL(Status__c,'Draft')),
    $Profile.Name = 'Distributor',
    ISCHANGED(Field1__c)
)
```

---

```
AND(NOT(ISPICKVAL(Status__c,'Draft')),
    $Profile.Name = 'Distributor',
    ISCHANGED(Field2__c)
)
```

...etc...

It would be easier to create two record types (one for Draft status, one for non-Draft), then create two page layouts, one where every field is set to editable, the other where everything is set to read-only, then assign the read-only layout to the Distributor profile for the non-Draft record type. You'll still need some validation rules if there are required fields (e.g. if Name is a text field), but this setup will require far less effort to maintain.